# Macports does not recognize pip-installed packages

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, macports

Until today, I have been using the macports version of `python27` and installing python packages through macports.  Today, I needed some packages which were not available through macports; I learned about pip and found them there.  After installing these packages through pip, however, I realized that neither pip nor macports could see what had been installed by the other.  So, for consistency, I decided to uninstall all macports packages, install `python27` and `py27-pip` through macports and then proceed to install all of my python packages through pip.

This worked fine, but since macports does not know about my pip-installed python packages, I ran into trouble when installing something else which depends on python (e.g., inkscape): macports tried to install its own version of, e.g. `py27-numpy` (already installed by pip) and then failed installation because it "already exists and does not belong to a registered port."

Is there a consistent way to use pip and to get macports to recognize that the python packages it might need for something else are already installed?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is: dont use Macports for installing Python's packages.

Macports is a general package manager and it registers installed packages in its database.

Pip is a package manager for Python so if you want to install Python package, use appropriate package management tool. Pip doesnt have it's own database to keep evidence about installed stuff - it just checks Python's path to see if the package is there (and that's what you want).

Sooner or later you'll use Virtualenv anyway and you'll need pip to install packages in there too so it's better to use it everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I wasn't planning to use macports to install python's packages, but it needs python to install other things (e.g., inkscape).  Is there a way to tell it that pip has already installed things like numpy and get it to use those?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to install your own version of numpy rather than using the MacPorts version?  You should stick to one or the other: (1) either install all packages you need using MacPorts ports and just fall back to manually installing via pip if there is no port for it (or, better, request that a port be created or updated); or (2) manage all packages manually via `pip`.  You can use `virtualenv` in either scenario.

Comment: I was hoping to use option (2), since pip seemed more comprehensive and I wanted a single manager for the packages.  But, many other programs that macports installs depend on python, so it will always try to install its own version.

Comment: This answer is not actually responsive to the question. It says, in order to have Python recognise packages, install them with pip. The question asks, what is necessary to have Macport ports (e.g. inkscape) recognise packages which were installed with pip?  We need an answer which says, "Here is how to make Inkscape installed by MacPorts work, using the Python pakcages from pip."

Answer (score 1):

Rather old question, but as I stumbled upon it, here goes:

- the only python related packages I install through macports myself are python and pip
- use pip to install python packages, but DON'T USE sudo! This is the recommended way to use pip anyways
- this will cause your pip-installed packages to live under ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages
- if a macports installed package has a python dependency, let it do it's thing (using sudo, which is the recommended way to run macports)
- Macports will install python packages under /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages thus avoiding any conflicts

It's rare that a macports package I install requires the installation of a macports-managed py39-*whatever* package but it happens. Either way, this way there is no confict.

At the end of the day, probably still best to use virtualenv for anything that has specific requirements, but at least this is a decent way to install things into your main environment.